# Is there a framework can realize Bayeux and hang in rensin？

Tags: comet, resin, bayeux

Look like ComeD can only extend jetty, is there a framework can realize Bayeux and hang in rensin, or other based on the long polling framework?

Answer (score 1):

The CometD project is fully portable and works in any Servlet 3.0 compliant servlet container, so it should work in Resin too, see http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java.

What you cannot get in Resin (I guess you meant Resin when you wrote "rensin") is WebSocket support because that is the only part of CometD that is Jetty-specific.
CometD is waiting for JSR 356 to standardize the WebSocket API in order to write the WebSocket support that will work in any compliant servlet container; this work has already been started in Jetty 9 and CometD 3.